# Console font color with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

Is there a way to make the grey messages that ExpressJS outputs the default console color (green in this case)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the logger settings. This gives you a pretty similar green color.

`app.use(express.logger('tiny'));`